# Сохранять web логи

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер

Установил чистый ubuntu 18.04 и все последние обновления. Имеется две сетевые карты. Одна смотрит в интернет. Вторая - в локальную сеть. Туда будет раздаваться интернет.

Нужно как-то быстро и просто вести логи всех запросов в интернет из локальной сети. Достаточно будет

- ip машины в локальной сети, отправившей запрос
- что смотрели ip адрес сервера
- когда смотрели

Если это не усложнит задачу, то хотелось бы ещё:

- mac адрес сетевой карты машины в локальной сети, от которой пошёл запрос
- не просто ip адрес сервера, на который запрос отправили, а url адрес.

Но последних два пункта не обязательны.

Логи должны вестить постоянно в фоне. И стартовать после перезагрузки. Отлично будет, если это будет не просто txt файл, а именно log, которые автоматически разбиваются по дням и архивируются (как syslog).

Как можно сделать это самым простым способом?

Comment: информацию можно получать скажем tcpdump. А логи сислога ничем от обычных txt файлов не отличаются. За их архивацию обычно вообще отвечают сторонние программы на подобии logrotate (не знаю какая в ubuntu по умолчанию, но замечу что в любом linux доступен десяток различных программ этого толка)

Comment: @Mike я вот не нашёл, как его запустить как демона, чтобы она работал себе на постоянной основе. Как его настроить под мои нужды?

Comment: я бы лучше копнул в сторону логирования напрямую с помощью `netfilter`/`iptables`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer можно подробнее?

Comment: @n.osennij, у `iptables` есть две специальные цели — `LOG` и `NFLOG`, первая отправляет сообщения в забитом в коде формате в лог ядра (`/proc/kmsg`), а вторая позволяет пересылать юзерспейсному демону, например [`ulogd`](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/index.html), который может форматировать всё произвольным образом или вообще писать прямо в БД...

Comment: Честно сказать, сам никогда не пользовался, но из шапки гугла: [вариант с LOG](https://habr.com/ru/post/259169/), [tl;dr-версия NFLOG](http://blog.grimmo.it/2016/05/05/iptables-logging-using-nflog-and-ulogd2-on-debian-jessie/), а вот здесь [NFLOG в конфигурации посложней](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2018/08/01/how-to-log-dropped-connections-from-iptables-firewall-using-netfilter-userspace-logging-daemon/)

Comment: тут же netflow надо, а не логи. с урл посложнее, может прокси?

Comment: прозрачный squid